# deallocating various pointers in a function that repeats several times

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

I have a void function that sends a struct value

my func' is repeated several times. the struct members were dinamically allocated. So how can I free them?

I guess that if I free them in the func' itself, it will destroy the struct object that has been sent.

```
void func(){

    typedef struct ENTRY {
        int entry_num;
        char* English_term;
        char** translations;
        enum types type;
    }ENTRY;


    ENTRY new_entry = { .entry_num = 0,
        .English_term = temp,
        .translations = (char**)malloc(tr_amnt * sizeof(char*)),
        .type = 0
    }
    ...
    ... 

    another_function(new_entry);

    // free all pointers?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you're not returning the pointers from the function in any way (neither via return statement nor via function parameters), you can `free()` the allocated memory pointed to by those pointers.

It's expected that the `another_function()` will have it's own copy of the arguments passed, if needed to retain the value beyond the function call.

Comment: So if I do want to return, I would actually have to return also the allocated pointers and free them at the main function?

Comment: Yes, you only free them once you're dine using the memory.

Comment: Re “It's expected that the `another_function()` will have [its] own copy of the arguments passed, if needed to retain the value beyond the function call’: This is a convention or contract that is not part of the programming language and should not be asserted without qualification. If OP does not know what that the specification of `another_function` includes this property, they should not rely on it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In that case, we will never be able to free any allocated memory, if they have ever been used as a function argument for another function call, is not it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, that is not a correct conclusion. What is correct or needed depends on what the specification of the called routine is. If OP were calling some standard library routine, we could generally assume it behaves in a way generally in accordance with the library. But they have given an example where the routine being called may be something custom to their application. We do not know what it does and should not assume.

Comment: Correct, same can be said about the `another_function()` also, right?